# Magento 1.9: Product price model increment with (quantity and price) step

Tags: magento-1.9, price-rules, custom-prices

Is it possible to have a mapping for product quantity and price in terms of step, instead of linear scaling? 
More specifically, a base price(x$) for base quantity(q) plus additive step price(y$) for every step quantity(p) increment and number of increments(n), so total price is (x + n*y)$ for total quantity (q + n*p) ?  Is it necessary to create new custom product type?